# How can I initialize a reference attribute in my class

Tags: c++

I have a class which has a private attribute which is a reference to another class:

```
class A {
public:
   A(); 
   A(B& anotherB);
private:
  B& bRef;
}
```

In my A(B& anotherB), I can do this:

```
  A::A(B& anotherB)
   : bRef(anotherB) {
}
```

But what about A()?  I tried this:

```
   A::A()
    : bRef(B()) {}
```

But I get this error 'error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘B&’ from a temporary of type ‘B’.

How can I call initialize B reference in A with the default constructor of B?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have a real instance to initialize it to.  Saying `: bRef(B())` creates a temporary which is immediately destroyed, thus your reference would be to an object that no longer exists, thus the compiler error.

You don't *need* to initialize it unless you're making some decision based on it not being initialized.  In that case you can have a `bool initialized;` member that you use to keep track of the state.

If you want to initialize it to something like `NULL`, use a pointer instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really want to use a reference but still keep your default constructor, you could set up a global (or file static) instance of B that represents a null or default state, whatever you want your default A to use.

```
A::A()
: bRef(nullB) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

With c++-11, you may build something like:

```
class A {
public:
   A(); 
   A(B& anotherB);
private:
  B& bRef = *(B*)(0);
  // Or assign bRef with an accessible ( static ) instance of `B` previously created elsewhere 
}
```

-- BUT : `bRef` being assigned a NULL pointer, You have the responsability to assign a valid instance of `B` as soon as you create an instance of `A`.

Be advised that this construct is a dangerous old-c style.

Answer (score 0):

You should model your class with reference field if you know that the field always hold a valid reference. In your case you have default constructor which you want your reference to point to a dummy value, it should be more appropriate to model it with pointer field. You cant assign NULL to reference nor it should point to a object create on the stack and only valid within the scope.

Comment: yeah sorry a typo, will fix it now

Answer (score 0):

References **always** refer to valid objects. So, there is no way to initialize bRef without a valid B object.

Suggestion: Consider making A::A() private and not implementing it.

Comment: I see.. Then I am curious why you need to add bRef in its initializer list.